# Изменение parent activity программно

Tags: java, android

Есть класс `MainActivity2` , в манифесте стоит его `parent activity` , после нажатии на кнопку activity открывается  , но parent activity  должен поменяться.

**Как** изменить `parent activity` программно?

Comment: для более подробного решения вашей проблемы, опишите ее подробнее (что изменить, когда изменить и тд)

Comment: @pavlofff Я изменил вопрос , не совсем точные данные дал.

Comment: по прежднему совершенно не понятно, что вы хотите. Изменить к какой активити в манифесте прикрепленно значение parent? думаю это невозможно. к тому же, данный атрибут влияет только на переход по кнопке назад. если вам нужен переход в другое активити, просто обработайте нажатие "назад" сами, а parent не указывайте вовсе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы никак не можете напрямую менять активити, которая в данный момент не на экране, так как она условно не существует (ее существование не гарантировано системой), соответственно в любой момент вы можете получить NPE.

Если вам требуется изменить что то в активити, которая в данный момент не отображается, вы можете передать туда информацию одним из доступных способов:

1. через `onActivityResult()` для вызова последующей активити с возвратом результата при ее закрытии.
2. через интент при прямом вызове активити
3. через хранилище данных, не зависящее от жизненного цикла (преференсы, БД, файл)

переданную одним из этих способов информацию, активити должна обработать и внести изменения в свой вид или свойства или что требуется изменить в момент, когда она появится на экране (у нее будет вызван метод `onCreate()` или другой жизненного цикла, подходящий вашим задачам)